# What time formatting is used within the blackout window for the REST interface /messageContact/{id}/send?

Tags: rest-api

the example given in the documentation looks like this:

```
"BlackoutWindow": {
    "UtcOffset": "-0500",
    "WindowStart": "1500",
    "WindowEnd": "2200"
},
```

Is this saying not to send a message from:

- 3pm to 10pm?
- 8pm to 3am due to the offset?
- Something else altogether?

TIA for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3pm to 10pm in the -0500 time zone (East Coast), which is also 8pm to 3am in the UTC time zone (London). In other words, WindowStart and WindowEnd are relative times, not absolute UTC times.