# BlackoutWindow usage?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I've done a search and this is the closest reference I could find...

[What time formatting is used within the blackout window for the REST interface /messageContact/{id}/send?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83569/what-time-formatting-is-used-within-the-blackout-window-for-the-rest-interface)

My question though is whether or not the API actually respects these values sent in.

We're calling the API found at https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/postMessageContactSend.html and it appears that no matter what values I attempt to use, I will get my SMS messages immediately.

Here are 2 examples I've tried:

```
"BlackoutWindow":{"UtcOffset":"-0500","WindowStart":"0200","WindowEnd":"0100"}
```

and

```
"BlackoutWindow":{"UtcOffset":"-0500","WindowStart":"0100","WindowEnd":"0200"}
```

If I'm correct, one statement is saying to blackout from 2AM - 1AM the following day (does it work that way) and the other is saying to block between 1AM and 2AM of the same day.

Yet when I sent texts, I got both sets instantly and this was performed at approximately 8:30 AM in the morning. So it's as if it didn't use the BlackoutWindow rule...

So I'm looking for confirmation on whether this is really respected or not when sent via API.  If so, what am I doing incorrectly here???

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? As of today, it seems like BlackoutWindow is NOT respected at all in the rest calls. Of course, SFMC has no idea.

Comment: Confirmed as a bug by SFMC. I'm doing my best to provide as much detail as possible so hopefully this gets fixed.